# Where can I learn how to create my own blockchain with a new transaction scheme?

Tags: altcoin-development

I am trying to create my own blockchain with my own transactions but there is not much information on how this works in detail. 
Basically I want to create a transaction with my own structure using blockchain. It is possible?

Comment: BTW, what programming language do you intend to use?

Comment: I do not care much about the programming language ... I just need to do it somehow!
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you are not finding many detailed resources about blockchain is because it is a new innovation and not widely understood. Most resources are scattered across blogs and code repositories. A few developer and programming guides are listed lower down.

The most valuable and primary resource is the [Bitcoin Core client](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) implementation - also called the *Satoshi reference client*.

It is possible to design and build a blockchain client from first principles. The design will require several components, and here are the basics:

- **P2P networking** - manage connections & send/receive messages and data
- a **Messaging protocol** - message and data format
- **Database** - store & retrieve block headers, blocks, transactions and previous spends (UTXOs)
- client **Behavior logic** - handle messages, protocol rules, coinbase rules, etc
- **Consensus logic** - gather, process and apply peer consensus about the validity of transactions, blocks and the unfolding chain
- **Coin generation** code - mining and proof-of-work (if any)
- general household code - logging, error handling, state maintenance, etc

That may seem daunting at first glance, but it is a worthwhile and achievable project.

Notice, that cryptography is not listed. This is because a private blockchain does not require secrets or obfuscation. However, if it is of interest, one can implement Bitcoin's Eliptic Curve library and address schema.

Before creating a blockchain client and protocol from first principles, it will be necessary to do some research about how the Bitcoin protocol works. [Mastering Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook) by Andreas Antonopoulos provides good insight. Other resources of interest:

- https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-documentation
- [This question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/18461/bitcoin-programming-book) has useful discussion and several pointers to learning resources.

Study how the reference client behaves, and read the reference client code, especially the file [main.cpp](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0.13/src/main.cpp) - *(linked to Core v0.13, since that file's code has been rationalized into separate files from v0.14 onwards)*

Also, there are several open source libraries that allow you to run barebones blockchain nodes and exchange protocol messages. Some libraries are better than others:

- [pychain](https://github.com/anax32/pychain) - basic blockchain prototype
- [PyCoin](https://github.com/xran-deex/PyCoin) - a Python Bitcoin clone
- [Zen System](https://zensystem.io/) - encrypt *everything* blockchain featuring communications, transactions and a DAO.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Actually the question would be: How can I create a private blockchain with my own transactions?

Comment: Is there any way to create the private blockchain in Java language?

Comment: Obviously, just do it in Java...