# How can I create a private blockchain with my own transactions?

Tags: blockchain

I need to create a transaction where Alice can write a message and send it to Bob, for example: Alice sends a "Hello" message to Bob, to achieve this, Alice creates a transaction and sends all her interconnected blockchain nodes. Each node validates that transaction (with some policy) and if a valid transaction sends the transaction back to all its connected nodes. Then the mining nodes add it to a block and also add that block to the blockchain. To be able to achieve all this procedure I have to modify some code blockchain (a code poorly documented). Would you know if it is feasible to do? Would you know if there is a place that can help me achieve it? Regards!.

Comment: Surely this is a duplicate to https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54853/where-can-i-learn-how-to-create-my-own-blockchain-with-a-new-transaction-scheme ? The answer here would be the same! :)

Comment: Is not the answer I expected :/

Comment: The example you give above is not very clear but it seems to describe the concept of what every blockchain basically does. The short answer to your question is "yes, it is feasible to mix communications and transactions in a blockchain framework". Zen is an example of such an implementation: https://zensystem.io/  It is based mostly on the Bitcoin Core code. You could clone the source code from GitHub and begin customizing it for your own design. About a "place" that can help you... I can only say that its all happening online - in forums, in chats and in the code repositories. Get busy! :)

Comment: I just added a couple of GitHub projects to get you started in my answer at https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/54863/38546

Comment: Thak for your answer!
I was trying to modify the bitcoin core code (to be able to add my own transactions) but the truth is very difficult to understand well that modify and where to modify in that code. Would you know where to start?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/seanseany/blockchain.js) there is a repository that allows you to add all kinds of data to a blockchain.
If you look at the "Data" field of each block you can add your own transaction in JSON format.